# Shapeless: IsHCons, implicit not found

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to make this rather silly example work, planning to then extend it to something more meaningful.

But no luck so far: I get `could not find implicit value for parameter ihc`

What am I missing?

```
sealed trait Field[T] { def name: String }
case class IntegerField(name: String) extends Field[Int]
val year = IntegerField("year")

val test = (year :: 23 :: HNil) :: (year :: 2 :: HNil) :: HNil

type TypedMap = IntegerField ::  Int  :: HNil

def get[L <: HList : <<:[TypedMap]#λ]
      (key: IntegerField, list: L)
      (implicit ihc: IsHCons.Aux[L, TypedMap, L]
    ): Option[Int] = {

  if( list == HNil ) return None
  val elem: TypedMap = list.head
  if( elem.head == key ) Some(elem.tail.head)
  else get(key, list.tail)

}

get(year, test)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `IsHCons.Aux[L, TypedMap, L]` you're asking for evidence that the hlist `L` has head `TypedMap` and tail `L`, which would mean that it's an infinite hlist, which isn't possible, since Scala doesn't allow this kind of arbitrarily recursive type (try writing something like `type Foo = Int :: Foo`, for example—you'll get a "illegal cyclic reference" error). It's also probably not what you want.

In general you're unlikely to use `IsHCons` much in Shapeless, since it's almost always better just to indicate the structure you want in the type. For example, the following two definitions do the same thing:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.IsHCons

def foo[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit ev: IsHCons[L]) = ev.head(l)
```

And:

```
def foo[H, T <: HList](l: H :: T) = l.head
```

But the second is obviously preferable (it's clearer, it doesn't require an extra type class instance to be found at compile time, etc.), and it's almost always possible to write whatever you're trying to do that way.

Also note that requiring an `IsHCons` instance means that the recursion here won't work as stated—you can't call `get` on an `HNil`, since the compiler can't prove that it's an `HCons` (because it's not).

Are you sure you need an hlist at all? If you're requiring that all members of the hlist are of type `TypedMap`, you might as well use Shapeless's `Sized` (if you want the type to capture the length) or even just a plain old `List`.

If you really, really want to use an `HList` here, I'd suggest writing a new type class:

```
trait FindField[L <: HList] {
  def find(key: IntegerField, l: L): Option[Int]
}

object FindField {
  implicit val findFieldHNil: FindField[HNil] = new FindField[HNil] {
    def find(key: IntegerField, l: HNil) = None
  }

  implicit def findFieldHCons[H <: TypedMap, T <: HList](implicit
    fft: FindField[T]
  ): FindField[H :: T] = new FindField[H :: T] {
    def find(key: IntegerField, l: H :: T) = if (l.head.head == key)
      Some(l.head.tail.head)
    else fft.find(key, l.tail)
  }
}

def get[L <: HList](key: IntegerField, l: L)(implicit
  ffl: FindField[L]
): Option[Int] = ffl.find(key, l)
```

And then:

```
scala> get(IntegerField("year"), test)
res3: Option[Int] = Some(23)

scala> get(IntegerField("foo"), test)
res4: Option[Int] = None
```

This is a pretty common pattern in Shapeless—you inductively describe how to perform an operation on an empty hlist, then on an hlist with a head prepended to a tail that you know how to perform the operation on, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I know that like this it looks stupid. My aim is to build something like shapeless `HMap`, but with a `get()` function that accepts a generic `Field[T]` instance instead of an `IntegerField`, `StringField`, ...
In your example, how do you recurse if the item you are looking for is not the first one? If I try to write `else find(key, l.tail)` I get `found   : T,  required: shapeless.::[H,T],` --- which is why I was trying `IsHCons.Aux`

Comment: Ah, good catch—I mis-typed, and have updated `findFieldHCons` so that it actually works.

Comment: Fantastic! Even the not-dumbed-down version works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped! I've also just updated the first comparison to make it a little more fair to `IsHCons` (because you don't need to specify the head and tail types in this simple case), but the argument still stands.